What size of screw does fit on the macbook keyboard frame?

Version of Macbook: Macbook Air M1 late 2020 A2337

I’ve replaced my macbook keyboard at home, but the new keyboard has a little gap between the topcase frame because I couldn’t insert the screws on there. The original macbook screws are not fit on the holes of the frame where the rivet screws should be inserted. I need an alternative screws for this task. Are there any recommendation screws to solve the problem?


When you say the original screws don’t fit, is it because they are one time use screws and damaged during removal or that you’re using a different part than came with your Mac? Also, use caution when ordering in case you choose to get a whole top case if you can’t source these as plastic rivets or screws . https://www.ifixit.com/Parts/MacBook_Air_13%22_Late_2020

@bmike I haven’t damaged at all on the topcase except the part where the rivet screws are inserted. I popped up most of the rivet screws for replacing the keyboard.

@bmike What I’ve been trying was to replace the rivets with pentalobe screws which are inserted on the edge of the keyboard like the video below does. https://youtu.be/-uaog_BBRso?si=EdmllbxqR__PGeBW?t=17m25s I didn’t use any extra screws that came from different mac.

@bmike I can’t buy the full topcase right now due to the financial problem. Buying extra side screws is inevitable to me. I need a screw which is a little bit bigger than the holes on the topcase.
